# Google Places - Get formatted address without user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have been sifting through documentation unsuccessfully and need help. I need to access the first value in Google places autocomplete or geocode the lat lng coords I have in Google Places. I am auto populating the field with say "Palo Alto" and need Google Places' first suggestion for an auto complete of that city. I have tried using the Google Geocode feature but the results are different than the Places API and therefore useless to me. Example places outputs Palo Alto, CA and the geocode feature outputs Palo Alto, CA USA. I have tried hacking it together by reverse geocoding the lat lng splitting the string above to only say Palo Alto and populating an input field that is hooked into a Places autocomplete, but I can't get it to trigger. I have a script written to pull the output from the autocomplete results; I just need to trigger it. I have tried using $('myCity').trigger('keypress'); once I have inserted Palo Alto into the input field to no avail. All suggestions on what steps to take next are welcome. I have also looked into the following code, but I want to do it without the map and i get a javascript error when i remove it. "TypeError: a is undefined [Break On This Error] (66 out of range 46)"

```
var lat = -130;
var lng = 37;
var request = {
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
};

var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(request, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {        
          console.log(results[i])
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a Text Search.

Go to [Places Library](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) and go down to **Text Search Requests**.

Heres an example:

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    query: 'restaurant'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Note: In your case change the request to this:

```
  var request = {
    query: 'Palo Alto'
  };
```